# On positive definite matrices and eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, positive-definite, symmetric-matrices

If I have symmetric matrix $A,$ then why is proving that all of the eigenvalues of $A$ are positive sufficient to show that $A$ is positive definite? Is this also true for non-symmetric matrices?

Comment: Thanks, but my teacher used the first one to prove that it's PD, why is this true?

Comment: @Carlo Your deleted answer is fixable: since the $P$ is orthogonal, $P^{-1} = P^\top$, and so the property of being positive-definite is indeed preserved.

Comment: May someone please share full answer

Comment: Are your matrices real or complex? Are vectors allowed to be complex? What is your definition of positive definite, $x^TAx>0$ or $\bar{x}^TAx>0$? It makes a difference to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

[By definition](https://www.math.utah.edu/%7Ezwick/Classes/Fall2012_2270/Lectures/Lecture33_with_Examples.pdf), a symmetric matrix $A$ is positive-definite whenever all of the eigenvalues of $A$ are positive. On the other hand, if $A$ is not symmetric, then $A$ cannot be positive-definite.

**Edit:** By the [Spectral Theorem](http://www.math.lsa.umich.edu/%7Ekesmith/SpectralTheoremW2017.pdf), a symmetric matrix is orthogonally diagonalizable, i.e., there exists an orthogonal matrix $P$ such that $A = P^T DP,$ where $D$ is the diagonal matrix whose nonzero entries are the eigenvalues of $A.$ By hypothesis that the eigenvalues of $A$ are positive, it follows that $D$ is a positive-definite matrix. Considering that $P$ is orthogonal (and hence invertible), the linear transformation determined by $f(x) = Px$ is bijective. Particularly, we have that $x^T A x > 0$ if and only if $y^T D y > 0,$ where $y = Px.$ Consequently, the matrix $A$ is positive-definite.

Comment: But we defined a matrix to be PD if x^TAx > 0 for every x !=0

Comment: Why you wrote "Consequently, the matrix 
A
 is positive-definite"? I understand everything before that but not this one

Comment: I have written the details after the claim. I will make it clearer in an edit.